# Audiokit plot waveform in going out of the View

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I was testing Microphone Analysis example provided in audiokit repo.
I have noticed that the plot drawing waveform out of its view. 
is there any solution to fix this ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just a UIView right, so you should be able clipToBounds:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622415-clipstobounds